# Dynamic Columns In Reporting Services Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, dynamic-columns

I have a data query that returns data in the following format:

```
Name    Period    Value
-----------------------------
Bob     Jan       123 
Bob     Feb       456 
Bob     Mar       789
Tom     Jan       321 
Tom     Feb       654 
Tom     Mar       987
Joe     Jan       147 
Joe     Feb       258 
Joe     Mar       369
```

The different periods are constant between names, but will be different between executions of the report (ie, I may query a report on Jan/Feb/Mar now, or Apr/May/Jun later). I'm trying to put that into a table in my Reporting Services report, that would look something like this:

```
Name    Jan    Feb    Mar
----------------------------
Bob     123    456    789
Tom     321    654    987
Joe     147    258    369
```

Can anyone point me to an example of doing something like that? I'm not even sure how to describe that 'rotation'(?) of the data. The columns should be dynamic based on what Period values are in the dataset.

Comment: The word you're looking for to describe the 'rotation' of rows into columns is a SQL pivot table. I wrote a brief explanation here: http://www.adamjamesnaylor.com/UsingPivotTablesInSQL.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer right after posting. Here's what I did.
 Created a new Tablix. Dragged the Name field to the data row of the first column. Dragged the Value column to the data row of the second column. Dragged the Period field to the *header* row of the second column. That created a new group, and a new second level header column. I then copied the value from that new top header column to the header cell below it, and deleted the whole new header row. When asked whether to delete the row and associated groups, or just row, choose *just the row*. You should be left with a Row Group and two Column Groups, and it should render as intended.